# SQLite create table with UNIQUE combination of columns

Tags: android, sqlite, primary-key, unique

I have looked through several sites for any useful documentation and have come up empty. The flow charts from the official site might as well be greek and examples I have attempted from other relevant posts on this site have gotten me errors. I am writing a simple app to place user input in a database, however I need a **combination of 2 columns to be unique**. From what I have seen this can be accomplished with UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY. **I also need some way of capturing the error to Toast the user that their input is faulty**. I know that I can do this in the Java side easily enough yet I would prefer not to loop through the table on every proposed insert.

This is what I have so far:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE inventory (category TEXT, itemNum TEXT, quantity INTEGER, price REAL, image INTEGER, UNIQUE(category, itemNum) ON CONFLICT FAIL;");
```

The table constructed properly until I added UNIQUE...

Which threw:
ERROR/SQLiteOpenHelper(1037): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ";": syntax error: CREATE TABLE inventory (category TEXT, itemNum TEXT, quantity INTEGER, price REAL, image INTEGER, CONSTRAINT unq UNIQUE(category, itemNum) ON CONFLICT FAIL;

EDIT:

... fill *ContentValues values* with user input.

```
try{
db.getWritableDatabase().insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, DatabaseHelper.CATEGORY, values);
fillItemNumbers();  // Updates screen       
}
catch(SQLiteConstraintException e)
{
Toast
.makeText(this, "User error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
.show();            
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mismatched parenthesis. There should be another `)` after `FAIL`.

Once you've sorted that, you can catch the exception that happens when the constraint is breached.

```java
try {
    // insert new data
} catch (SQLiteConstraintException e) {
    Toast.makeText(context, 
                   "The combination of A and B must be unique",
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Facepalm! I now return my programmer's card and retreat quietly to sulk in a corner.

Comment: Any thoughts on the second question? I also need some way of capturing the error to Toast the user that their input is faulty

Comment: Re-edited my question using your code. The database is not allowing the duplicate entry now yet no toast is popping.

Comment: Indeed:

03-29 15:05:53.453: ERROR/Database(1142): Error inserting itemNum=TTA23457 image=7 quantity=6 category=Case price=99.99



03-29 15:05:53.453: ERROR/Database(1142): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed

Comment: The line it references in my code is the first one in the try-catch block. I would think that the block would catch this error. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried `insertWithOnConflict` with the `CONFLICT_FAIL` constant?

Comment: By George! I think you've got it! That fixed it; thank you Barak.

Comment: i facepalmed too...i thought i couldn't be as stupid as @AnthonyW... :D